# How do I increment strings in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I can increment integers in Vim using `<Ctrl>-a`. The docs seem to say that if I set `nrformats` to `"octal,hex,alpha"` (which I am trying to do with `:set nrformats="octal,hex,alpha"`) then `<Ctrl>-a` will increment `a` to `b`, `007` to `010`, and `0x09` to `0x0f`, but those examples are not working for me (I just a get a beep for `a`, `007` turns into `008`, and `0x09` turns into `0x10`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quotes were the problem, I should have typed `:set nrformats=octal,hex,alpha` or `:se nf=octal,hex,alpha`.